# Unexpected Back Stack Behavior

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a notification that launches an Activity (C) for which I build a back stack to adhere to the Android guidelines, the back stack:

```
C
B
A
```

The user clicks the notification, it opens C, then if they press back it goes to B, then to A, then to the home screen.  This works as expected.

If the user clicks the notification (opening C), then presses the home button to go to the home screen, then launches the app from the home screen, it opens A, not C as I expect and want.  If they then press back (from A) it goes to C, then B, then A.  So, when they launch the app from the home screen in this situation, it's creating a new Activity A and putting it on top of the existing stack instead of opening the top of the existing stack (C), so the stack would look like:

```
A
C
B
A
```

My code creating the back stack and launch intent for the notification:

```
/* Build the back stack for navigation */
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
/* Pairing List */
Intent intent = new Intent( this, A.class );
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( intent );
/* Pairing */
intent = new Intent( this, B.class );
intent.putExtra( "id", briefing.getLeg().getDay().getPairing().getId() );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( intent );

/* Create a launch intent and notification */
intent = new Intent( this, C.class );
intent.putExtra( "date", briefing.getLeg().getDay().getDate() );
intent.putExtra( "id", briefing.getLeg().getId() );
intent.putExtra( "briefing", true );

stackBuilder.addNextIntent( intent );
pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
```

Activity declarations in my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".C" />
<activity
    android:name=".A"
>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".B" />
```

I think it's a problem with the flags I'm setting on the intents, but I'm not sure what I need to change.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you launch your application (the first time) from the installer (or from an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ or from the web browser)? If so, there is a bug in Android that causes the behaviour you've described. Try to launch the app (the first time) from teh HOME screen instead and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you mean the first launch after installing it?  That was via Eclipse, though the device has been rebooted since then and then the app launched from the home screen.

Comment: I've determined that the flags I've added in the above code make no difference.  I've also determined that this behaviour only happens when the root activity (A) is put into the back stack.  If I only add B and C without A, then it works as expected.  If I add A, then B, then C, then the problem crops up.  I don't know how to fix this though!

Comment: If you remove your call to `setFlags()` on the `Intent` for `A` does the problem persist? If so, try adding `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` to the `Intent` for `A` instead.

Comment: Removing the `setFlags()` call that I had changes nothing, I tried `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` and it still does the same thing, I tried `addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED )` on the intent that launches Activity C and home->relaunch works, but when selecting the notification Activity C doesn't show, it seems to get lost and it displays Activity B...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal behavior. Only the activity on top can be active. So if you start A it will be pushed on top.

If you want it to start a new Task(With its own back stack) I think you should set your launchmode to "singleInstance" in your Manifest. This creates a new "task" each time you start Activity A. With Intents you should be able to build a Back stack A->B->C.

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html